# C++ error:Assignment of read-only location

Tags: c++

Please help me to find the problem, I am totally lost why I can't modify my list. As you can see I did not declared anything as const..

Here is the code:

```
struct Carte 
{   
    Carte(initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>  iInp){}
    initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> aVect;
};


.....
void changeValue(Carte& iCarte, int iValA, int iValB)
{   
    initializer_list<initializer_list<int>> carte = iCarte.aVect;
    initializer_list<initializer_list<int> >::iterator carte_iterator;
    initializer_list<int>::iterator carteRow_iterator;

    //changing the value
    int aLocalI = 0;
    int aLocalJ = 0;

    for(carte_iterator = carte.begin();carte_iterator!=carte.end();++carte_iterator) 
    {
        if (aLocalI == iValA)
        {
            for(carteRow_iterator = (*carte_iterator).begin();carteRow_iterator!=(*carte_iterator).end();++carteRow_iterator) 
            {
                if (aLocalJ == iValB)
                {                   
                    *carteRow_iterator = 1; // ERROR HERE
                }
                aLocalJ++;
            }
        }
        aLocalI++;
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
Julia

Comment: Why are you using `initializer_list` in the first place? It is meant to be used as a proxy object.

Comment: Hi, tnx for you answer! In my assignment I have to start with writting the structure Care that can be used as Carte aCarte = {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2},{3,3,3}} in main. I tried to used the vector in my structure but got error "Can't convert from initializer_list to vector"... pffff

Answer (score 3):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`.

The elements of an `initializer_list` are *always* `const`, and thus `*carteRow_iterator` is `const`.

If you want a modifiable list of objects, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.